# accessing minimum and maximum values from date range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use date range slider taking reference from [here](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html#executingMethods)
everything went as per the documentation and I got the slider . now I need to access the minimum and maximum values from slider during movement. I tried to use min/max. bind as given in documentation. I couldn't acheive it.
my code is

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

```js
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    range: {
        min: new Date(2012, 0, 1)
    },
    bounds: {
        min: new Date(2012, 0, 1,00,00,00),
        max: new Date(2014, 11, 31, 12, 59, 59)
    },
    defaultValues: {
        min: new Date(2012, 0, 10,00,00,00),
        max: new Date(2012, 11, 31,00,00,00)
    },
});
```

how can I access the value as `console.log()` when the slider moves.

Answer (score 0):

From the API link you posted:

> Use the event valuesChanged when you want to intercept events once values are chosen. This event is only triggered once after a move.

```
$("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function(e, data){
     console.log("Values just changed. min: " + data.values.min + " max: " + data.values.max);
});
```

Comment: I have tried it but it's not working. how can I use it it code? might i could have mistaken in formatting within code.

Comment: You can use it exactly as it's written there. Without seeing what code you've written to try this I can't really guide you